# How to find the difference between two plots?

Tags: plotting

I have the following analytical plot.

```
i2k[i_] = 1/2 (i - 1) 
pixx = k^2 Exp[-2 k^2 Sin[(t)/2]^2 ](-Sin[2t] - Sin[t](1-k^2 Sin[t]^2));
piyy = k^2 Exp[ -2 k^2 Sin[(t)/2 ]^2 ](-4Sin[t]Sin[(t)/2]^2 - Sin[t](1-4k^2 Sin[(t)/2]^4));
pixy = k^2 Exp[-2k^2 Sin[(t)/2 ]^2 ](2Cos[t]Sin[(t)/2]^2 + Sin[t]^2 - 2 k^2 Sin[(t)/2]^2 Sin[t]^2);

xxrot = Cos[t + 2.0 - \[Pi] / 2]^2 pixx + 
   Sin[t + 2.0 - \[Pi] / 2]^2 piyy - 
   Sin[2 (t + 2.0 - \[Pi] / 2)] pixy;

xxrotplt = 
 Plot[ xxrot /. k -> -i2k[6] /. t -> t - 2 // Evaluate, {t, 666 0.01, 
   950 0.01}, PlotRange -> All, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 40], PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Then my code produced the following result. `s11resp` is the data from the code which I can not have here for some reasons. It is a {30000, 1, 512, 1} dimension list.

```
s11pltcc = 
 ListLinePlot[Re@s11resp[[666 ;; 950, 1, 6, 1]], PlotRange -> All,  
  DataRange -> {665 0.01, 949 0.01} , PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 40]]
```

[image]

Now I should compare the code and analytic result. The problem is if we show them together the difference is invisible.

[image]

My question is how to make the difference between the code and analytical results visible?
I appreciate it if you could help me.

Comment: You could use `PlotStyle->Dashed` in one plot and `Show[...]`

Comment: Is it also possible to somehow plot the subtraction of the two? My problem is then having a list of data and an analytical formula. It is not clear to me how to plot the subtraction.

Comment: If you know how the data was sampled, why not sample your analytic function at the same points, then compare the two?

Answer (score 1):

To compare two nearly identical plots

```
plot1=Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,2 Pi},PlotStyle->Red];
plot2=Plot[Sin[x],{x,0,2 Pi},PlotStyle->{Dashed,Black}];
Show[plot1,plot2]
```

[image]

**addendum**

Suppose we have an approximation

```
sin = Function[x, Sin[x] (1 + RandomReal[{-.01, .01}])]
```

we can plot the difference easily

```
Plot[{Sin[x] - sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi} ]
```

[image]

If you want to compare with data try

```
data=Table[{x,sin[x]},{x,RandomReal[{0,2Pi},10]}]; 
error=Map[Sin[#[[1]]]-#[[2]]&,data]&
ListPlot[error]
```

[image]

Perhaps ``` Needs["ErrorBarPlots``"] ``` might find your interest!

Comment: To show the accuracy of a code, this is not sufficient. I need to show the difference in a more robust way. Imagine you want to see the convergence of the code result for a bigger time step in your simulation. Then every time you produce the same comparison because the changes are so tiny.

Comment: In your question you compared the two plots not their difference!